Why do the sizes of the final saved images remain the same even though different quality parameters are used when saving images in heif format?
I save Bitmap into a jpg file.
Setting different quality parameters with '98　　95　　90　　85',
the final save image file sizes are different as bellow :
3994kb   3337kb  2178kb  1681kb
File size decreases sequentially with expectation.


I use HeifWriter to write Bitmap into a heif file.
implementation "androidx.heifwriter:heifwriter:1.1.0-alpha02"
The width and height of the Bitmap are 3272 x 4096.
the final saved image file remain the same size with 62kb.

The key code for 'HeifWriter' and 'setQuality'

When I debug into the heifwriter code, it will execute here:
https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:heifwriter/heifwriter/src/main/java/androidx/heifwriter/EncoderBase.java;l=367-368
and logging:

2024-04-28 14:04:17.064 12419-12604/com.sodino D/EncoderBase: Setting bitrate mode to constant quality
2024-04-28 14:04:17.064 12419-12604/com.sodino D/EncoderBase: Quality range: [0, 100]

Why is the final saved file size still the same when using different quality paraters?

It likely depends on the hardware supported by your device. The writer ends up doing this: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:heifwriter/heifwriter/src/main/java/androidx/heifwriter/EncoderBase.java;l=360-386 so you would need to work out whether you are in constant quality or variable quality, then what the supported ranges are on your device.

it will invoke : codecFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_QUALITY, myQualityParam)
@BradHards
log:
2024-04-28 14:04:17.064 12419-12604/com.sodino D/EncoderBase: Setting bitrate mode to constant quality
2024-04-28 14:04:17.064 12419-12604/com.sodino D/EncoderBase: Quality range: [0, 100]
https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:heifwriter/heifwriter/src/main/java/androidx/heifwriter/EncoderBase.java;l=362-368

Please work through the range info, then add that to your question. I can't read logs in the comments....

Curious. What is the original size, width and height of the BMP file that you started with? I'd expect most JPEG encoders to preserve width and height (in this case with aspect ratio 93:124). Never tried HeifWriter which has apparently padded? or interpolated it  inexplicably to aspect ratio 409:512. Unless the original image is extremely compressible it will be a total basket case compressed to 62kb.

jpg and heif use different pictures for testing.@MartinBrown    The point of the question is that heif uses different quality parameters for the same picture. Why are the saved pictures the same size?

What quality is being set for each value you put in? That is, what is the value associated with MediaFormat.KEY_QUALITY?  What are qualityRange.lower() and qualityRange.upper() returning?

98 95 90 85;
As shown in the file name on the screenshot.@BradHards

@sodino: you misunderstand me. What are the actual values in lines 367 and 368 of EncoderBase?

If you are testing a compression program you need to use the same test image as input for both. Otherwise you are comparing apples with oranges. The heif image sounds like it must be either white cat in a snowstorm or black cat in a coal cellar to be so very compressible. Feed the same image to both programs and we might make some progress. Best guess so far is user error setting the quality parameters for the heif encoder or that the heif image is essentially featureless and blank..

It's the same test image for heif test.@MartinBrown
